# Reference a service in object construction before the service is built. C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RunningGameService>(); 

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("GameGroupsAuthorisationConnect", policy =>
    {
        policy.Requirements.Add(new GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirement());
    });
});
```

Hi,
The problem I have is that the GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirement is dependent on RunningGameService, and hence it requires a reference to it in the constructor.

I'm a tad lost with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A requirement should not depend on a service; it just defines the parameters that are applicable for the authorization.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies#requirements)

> An authorization requirement is a collection of data parameters that a policy can use to evaluate the current user principal.

For example

```
public class GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{ 
    // Any properties in case applicable.
}
```

It is the accompanying [`AuthorizationHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies#authorization-handlers) that deals with the requirement that can have services injected.

```
public class GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirementHandler  
    : AuthorizationHandler<GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirement>
{
    public GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirementHandler(
        RunningGameService runningGameService
        /* Inject other services here */ 
        )
    { 
        // ...
    } 

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context, GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirement requirement
        )
    {
        // ...
        
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

That handler gets registered as below. Doing so it gets its services resolved from the DI container.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirementHandler>();
```

See [Dependency injection in requirement handlers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/dependencyinjection).

The way you defined your policy can stay as-is.

```
options.AddPolicy("GameGroupsAuthorisationConnect", policy =>
{
    policy.Requirements.Add(new GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirement());
});
```

Comment: Makes sense, I was following the example at the end of this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0
If I follow what you suggested, would the handler need to be present in the .AddPolicy part too? If not how would that policy know to use that handler? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to change your policy definition. The`new GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirement()` you have in `policy.Requirements.Add(new GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirement())` instructs the lookup for an `AuthorizationHandler<T>` which has `T` of type `GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirement`. That is the `GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirementHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [an overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addsingleton(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-type-system-object)) of `AddSingleton` that accepts an instance instead of a generic parameter, like this:

```
// Obviously you need to satisfy _this_ service's required constructor params here...
var rgService = new RunningGameService(...); 
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RunningGameService>(rgService); 

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("GameGroupsAuthorisationConnect", policy =>
    {
        policy.Requirements.Add(new GameGroupsAuthorisationConnectRequirement(rgService));
    });
});
```